# success actions runs multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js, redux-saga

I am fetching the data from server using **redux-saga** for async operation. I could fetch the data but I don't think I am doing efficiently. Because my `EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_SUCCESS` action runs multiple time. Before giving an example i want to clarify my app structure.

> AdminDashboard(admin/dashboard) - parent component which has
>   SideNavigation and Routes component as a children.
>
> SideNavigation has links which when clicked will show data in the
>   middle of the page, just aside SideNavigation.

Now the problem. When i go to route /admin/dashboard/email_service, i get the data which i am expecting. After that if i click on some other links and return back to the email_service then success action gets fired multiple times and it goes on increasing and increasing and increasing.

**index.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchEmailService: () => dispatch(fetchEmailService())
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  email: selectEmailService()
});

class EmailService extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    emailService: {
      api_key: "",
      domain: ""
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchEmailService();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    if (nextProps.email) {
      nextProps.email
        .entrySeq()
        .map(([key, value]) => {
          this.setState(state => ({
            emailService: { ...state.emailService, [key]: value }
          }));
        })
        .toArray();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { emailService, errors } = this.state;
    const { email } = this.props;
    if (email.size === 0) {
      return <div>fetching...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="api_key"
          type="text"
          value={emailService.api_key}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          error={errors.api_key}
        />
        <TextFieldGroup
          name="domain"
          type="text"
          value={emailService.domain}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailService);


reducer.js

function emailServiceState(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST:
      return state.set("requesting", true).set("successful", false);
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return state.set("successful", true).set("emailService", fromJS(action.emailService.data));
    case EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_FAILURE:
      return state.set("error", action.error);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

selectors.js

export const selectEmailService = () => state =>
  state.getIn(["emailService", "emailService"]);

sagas.js

function* fetchemailService(action) {
  yield call(
    EmailApi.get(
      "api/configuration/email-service",
      emailServiceFetched,
      emailServiceFetchingError
    )
  );
}

function* emailServiceWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST, fetchemailService);
}

export default [emailServiceWatcher];
```

[image]

Comment: where do you call `sagaMiddleware.run`?, it looks like on navigation you run saga middleware again? also if you log inside your `fetchemailService` generator function, how many times is it called after receiving `EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST`

Comment: Here is my github repo. I think sharing repo will be good because i am doing async route https://github.com/Tushant/dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Ok i looked at your repo and i found the issue:

This is the code inside `EmailService/sagas.js`, check the comments i added.

```
function* setupemailService(action) {
  const successWatcher = yield fork(redirectOnSuccess);
  yield fork(...);

  // 1. On LOCATION_CHANGE you are only cancelling the `successWatcher`
  yield take([LOCATION_CHANGE, EMAIL_SERVICE_SETUP_FAILURE]);
  yield cancel(successWatcher);
}

function* emailServiceWatcher() {

  yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_SETUP_REQUEST, setupemailService);

  // 2. you never cancelled `EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST` watcher
  yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST, fetchemailService);
}

export default [emailServiceWatcher];
```

What you need to do is something like this

```
function* emailServiceWatcher() {
  const setupeWatcher = yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_SETUP_REQUEST, setupemailService);
  const fetchWatcher = yield takeLatest(EMAIL_SERVICE_FETCH_REQUEST, fetchemailService);
  // Cancel these watchers on LOCATION_CHANGE
  yield take([LOCATION_CHANGE]);
  yield cancel(setupeWatcher);
  yield cancel(fetcheWatcher);

}
```

Comment: Have you tested those? I did change the async sagas code which worked for me either but your solution will work for other time too.